# Update functionality in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am newbie to React and I am trying to do update on react. I don't get the exact logic to make it and hence I need your help.
On click of update, I managed to get the values of selected contact but later on, i don't get how to populate those value onto input text boxes and again on submit after change of values, update the selected contact. I came across onChange but I don't understand.

Clues i knew: 
 this.refs.name.value and this.refs.number.value are values which are in input textbox . And on update, we need to set these value into the state on that corresponding index.

My code and screenshot is below: 
**Person.js** - number is taken as the key , considering individual number is unique

```
 editcontact(id){
     this.props.onChange(id);
   }
  render() {

          return(

            <div className="panel panel-default">
              <div className="panel-heading">
              <h4>{this.props.detail.name}  </h4>
              <a className="b" href="#" onClick={this.deletecontact.bind(this,this.props.detail.number)}> Delete </a>
              &nbsp;
              <a className="b" href="#" onClick={this.editcontact.bind(this,this.props.detail.number)}> Update </a>
              </div>

               <h6 className="panel-body">{this.props.detail.number}</h6>
            </div>
            </div>
          )
        }
```

It is passed to **Contact.js**

```
editcontact(id)
 {
   this.props.onChange(id);
 }
  render() {
     var details;
     if(this.props.data){
        details=this.props.data.map(dts=>{
          return(
            <Person key={dts.number} detail={dts} onChange={this.editcontact.bind(this)} onDelete={this.deletecontact.bind(this)}></Person>
          )
        })
```

}

Then comes **App.js**

```
  handleEdit(id){
      console.log(id);
      let cts=this.state.contacts;
      let index=cts.findIndex( x => x.number === id);
      console.log(cts[index]);
  this.setState({ selectedContact: cts[index]; });

        }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <div className="page-header">

          <h2>Contact list</h2>
        </div>
        <AddContact newOne={this.state.selectedContact} addcontact={this.handleAddition.bind(this)}></AddContact>
         <Contact onChange={this.handleEdit.bind(this)} onDelete={this.handleDelete.bind(this)} data={this.state.contacts}> </Contact>
      </div>

    );
```

}

**AddContact.js**

```
    constructor(){
    super();
    this.state={
      newContact:{
        name:'',
        number:''
      }
    }
  }
    addcontact(e){
    //   console.log(this.refs.name.value);\
    e.preventDefault();
       this.setState({
         newContact:{
           name: this.refs.name.value,
           number:this.refs.number.value
         }
       },function(){
         console.log(this.state.newContact);
         this.props.addcontact(this.state.newContact);
       })
        this.refs.name.value="";
        this.refs.number.value="";
    }



      render() {
             console.log(this.props.newOne);
        return (
          <div className="col-md-6">
          <form  onSubmit={this.addcontact.bind(this)}>
          <div className="form-group">
          <label>Name </label>
          <input className="form-control" type="text" ref="name" />
          </div>
          <div className="form-group">
          <label>Number</label>
          <input className="form-control" type="number" ref="number" />
          </div>
          <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
          </form>
          </div>
        );
      }
    }
```

[image]

Comment: That logic would go in your `AddContact` component, pass a props using the `setState` and `state`, Could you show the `AddContact` component?

Comment: I have added it too now.

Answer (score 0):

what you need is to tell your component that you have a new state and you want it to re-render.

```
 handleEdit(id){
      console.log(id);
      let cts=this.state.contacts;
      let index=cts.findIndex( x => x.number === id);
      this.setState({ selectedContact: cts[index]; });
 }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <div className="page-header">

          <h2>Contact list</h2>
        </div>
        <AddContact addcontact={this.handleAddition.bind(this)}></AddContact>
         <Contact onChange={this.handleEdit.bind(this)} onDelete={this.handleDelete.bind(this)} data={this.state.contacts}> </Contact>
      </div>

    );
```

with the `setState` function you updating the state of this compoent and also make it to re-render. now you can decide what you want to do with this data: `this.state.selectedContact` like passing it to `AddContact`

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `.bind(this...` there is no reason to do it. Use `attribute={() => this.functionName()}`

Don't use different naming, use some pattern for attributes names. e.g. `addcontact` should be `addContact`

Don't use so long lines. Use Eslint to show you all of such tips.

It's really hard to read your code now, make it more readable and you will have better time editing it yourself.

And now to have update, i would suggest using pure functional component to display things and higher order component to manage state of data.

```
(props) => <form> .... <input value={props.email} /> ... </form;
```

and in parent component, which is responsible for all data management add state. In state you can save values and pass it into child components using props.

When you will advance in React, you will start using extra libraries to manage state of the app, e.g. Redux. It makes similar thing, but all app's state is in one place and then you can access it from any part of the app. E.g. you show these inputs, then jump to another state of app to add some other thing and then you can easily jump back to this state and still have input's values that are partly entered.

Just save values in state. No matter how you manage your app's state and push values to display components using props. Google, read, check some videos on Youtube and you will get it.

https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/thinking-in-react.html

Comment: using anonymous function is also a bad practice because they are created on every `render` run - it's better to use `bind` in `constructor`

Comment: This answer still needs to address OP's understanding of how to use setState. Using an example would be lot nicer IMHO. Person is naive to the area.

Comment: @NagarajTantri yes, agree, that's why i added link to "Thinking in react" article which shows and talks about props, state and components in general, I don't find useful duplicating content